# How to retrieve the querystring in a Silverlight class library?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, query-string

I'm Buiding a Silverlight 3 class library that needs to get a hold of the querystring. Now I know that in a SilverLight app, you can get a hold of it via the `HtmlPage` class. This doesn't work for a Silverlight class library. In a class library used in ASP.NET you could get hold of the current context through `HttpContext.Current`. Does Silverlight 3 have something like that?

How to retrieve the querystring in a Silverlight class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no reason why HtmlPage class wouldn't work in a Silverlight class library.

You will of course need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Browser.dll` in order to use it if you haven't already done so.

Comment: You're right! I don't happened yesterday, but this is another goof up of mine. Thanks!